# Rails devise without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and i am trying to allow user to modify their information without providing their information. I have followed the tutorial https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password.

I have this link to allow user to change their own settings

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
```

What I did his follow

```
rails g controller Registration
```

In the registrations controller replace the content with this

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
    password_changed = !params[:user][:password].empty?

    successfully_updated = if email_changed or password_changed
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

And in route.rb file i did this

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

But it still bring me to the folder /views/devise/registration/edit.erb.html instead of bringing me to /views/registrations/edit.erb.html. I also restarted the server and my computer but no clue what else to do

Update: Note(customers = Users)

```
Started GET "/customers/edit.2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-09 20:06:03 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as 
  [1m[35mCustomer Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mPage Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` [0m
  [1m[35mTag Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` 
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_iewrap.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_search_tags.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_thirdcol.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_link.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 41ms (Views: 36.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-09 20:06:04 -0500
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (5ms)


Started GET "/assets/activity_managers.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-09 20:06:04 -0500
Served asset /activity_managers.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

this is the path i get to

```
http://localhost:3000/customers/edit.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the name and location of your file wrong.

1. The file should be called `edit.html.erb`, **not** `edit.erb.html`.
2. The file should be localed in `app/views/registrations`.

Also, whenever a url has `.id` appended at the end, it means that you are passing something to the url helper that you shouldn't be. So in this case, you can remove the `current_user` argument and use your link like this:

```
<%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %>
```

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct, the file name is edit.html.erb it was a spelling error on my part for this forum, the second link i try your but still process the default devise views. I also note that my edit file has only html code for testing purpose maybe would this cause an issue.

Comment: Did you use the command `rails generate devise:views` to generate your views?

Comment: If you did, you have to make sure that you do **not** have an `edit.html.erb` file in `app\views\devise\registrations`.

Comment: my route had an extra devise_for that i forgot to take off. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, uncomment this line `config.scoped_views = true` then restart Rails server. Also check if your `edit.erb.html` is in the right directory, it may be need to be in `app/views/users/registrations/`.

**UPDATE**:
You need to define `edit` method in your `RegistrationsController` because without it will inherit from Devise's `RegistrationsController` and consequently render Devises's views. Just add these two lines to the controller and it should work.

```
def edit
end
```

Comment: I just try to uncomment the line and try to put into a folder users/registrations/edit.erb.html and it did'nt work. I also try to restart the server.

Comment: I added it, nothing happened, i should mention does that before this i the following rails g devise:views i don't know if it changes anything!!

Comment: Could you please add Rails server log for the GET request to `RegistrationController#edit` to your question?

Comment: Added the development logs, where this is starting, let me know if its not what i should see. or if your missing something

Comment: How did you make users to be customers? Reading the logs, `edit` action is still processed by Devise, so what about `update` action, is it processed by Devise too or your controller?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I made customers has my model user was for this forum purpose, The controller his still the same has previously, dough my edit.html.erb has no form or anything just for testing purpose i actully just put html so i could see, would this cause an issue with my update controller?